# How can i filter C# dataGridView across all field names?

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter

I see [in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2h7C-IL-FB8) its quite easy to add a textbox and have it drive the filtering of a datagridView.  The issue is in this video it seems you have to specific which column to filter based on.

```
 RowFilter = "FirstName like "%' + searchText.Text + '%"
```

but what if I want it to check all of the fields and show the row if any column has my search string in it

Comment: This video is now unavailable, do you have any sample code from this nowadays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to loop through each column in your row and append an OR comparison

This is really stupid code, but hopefully gives you the gist of it. Something like:

```
StringBuilder filter = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var column in dataGridView.Columns)
{
   if(filter.ToString() == "")
   {
       filter.Append(column.Name + " like '" + searchText.Text + "'");
   }
   else 
   {
      filter.Append(" OR ");
      filter.Append(column.Name + " like '" + searchText.Text + "'");
   }
}

RowFilter = filter.ToString();
```

Comment: I am getting this error running that code "Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String"

Comment: @leora oops, sorry. changed the syntax to reflect using DataGridView. I had DataTable on the brain I guess ;)

Comment: @leora, Tom has right idea, but you can't do a like on an int as stated... you'll have to check the "column" data type and only do for fields that are character based.

Comment: @DRapp - why can't i search on numeric field?

Comment: @leora, you can, but you'll have to adjust the query to convert the numeric to a string, THEN you can apply the "like".

Comment: Yea this wasn't mean to be taken verbatim by any means. Just trying to point you in the right general direction...

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate all reasonable columns and get "like" filter like this:

```
var search = "search request";
var columnsList = dataGridView.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
    .Where(x => x.Visible && x.ValueType == typeof(string))
    .Select(x => x.DataPropertyName);
var filter = string.Join(" OR ", columnsList.Select(x => $"{x} like '%{search}%'"));
```