# How to filter datagridview by searching all columns

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
    bs.Filter = "ColumnName like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
}
```

I dont want to specify column. How can i search data in all columns?

Comment: seems like duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952279/how-can-i-filter-c-sharp-datagridview-across-all-field-names

Comment: Do specify an all-pass filter? Or none at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering DataGridView without changing datasource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)

Comment: Jan Greve none at all.

Comment: @kassi,@webo80 i tried that answer but the code doesnt work properly. I coulnt find clean answer about this on web.

Comment: @Koray what does that mean "doesnt work properly"? Do you get an exception or is the result not the one you expected?

Answer (score 1):

for sample try find four value from textBoxes in a row:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Query = "";
    if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty)
        Query += "ColumnName like '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%' and ";
    if (textBox2.Text != string.Empty)
        Query += "ColumnName2 like '%" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "%' and ";
    if (textBox3.Text != string.Empty)
        Query += "ColumnName3 like '%" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + "%' and ";
    if (textBox4.Text != string.Empty)
        Query += "ColumnName4 Like '%" + textBox4.Text.Trim() + "%' and ";
    Query += "1 = 1";
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = Query;

}
```

or find it in all columns:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Query = "";
    if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty)
        Query += "ColumnName like '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%' or ";
    if (textBox2.Text != string.Empty)
        Query += "ColumnName2 like '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%' or ";
    if (textBox3.Text != string.Empty)
        Query += "ColumnName3 like '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%' or ";
    if (textBox4.Text != string.Empty)
        Query += "ColumnName4 Like '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%' or ";
    Query += "1 = 1";
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = Query;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all reasonable columns and apply "like" filter like this:

```
var search = "search request";
var columnsList = dataGridView.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
    .Where(x => x.Visible && x.ValueType == typeof(string))
    .Select(x => x.DataPropertyName);
var filter = string.Join(" OR ", columnsList.Select(x => $"{x} like '%{search}%'"));

bindingSource.Filter = filter;
```